# Photon unity respawn игрока

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Не работает респавн игрока не в какую. Я перерыл ВСЁЁЁЁЁ, я не понимаю в чём дело... ПОМОГИТЕ!

```
public GameObject player;
    public Transform SpawnTeam2;
    [PunRPC]
    public void RPC_HpChecker()
    {
        if(view.IsMine)
        {
            if(HP <= 0)
            {
            player.transform.position = SpawnTeam2.transform.position;
                HP = 100f;
                Debug.Log("Pppppp");
            }
        }
    }


    [PunRPC]
    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "Destroyer" && view.IsMine)
        {
            HP -= 100f;
            Debug.Log("-50HP");
            view.RPC("RPC_HpChecker",RpcTarget.All);
        }
    }
```

Comment: А что не так? Это крик души...

Comment: player.transform.position = SpawnTeam2.transform.position; Он не переносит его на эту точку, я не понимаю в чём дело. Пытался как подключившись к серверу, как и оффлайн, ни в какую. Ошибок так же нет. Когда убираю точку (SpawnTeam2) из инспектора игрока, он жалуется что его нет, а когда добавляю, при соприкосновении с коллайдером "Destroyer" ничего не происходит.